# Z-index not working, even when paired with 'position'

Tags: z-index

I've posted the [source to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P52Me/).

As you'll be able to see, the caption appears below the images. I've tried pairing z-index with position as suggested in another stackoverflow thread, but still no luck.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: absolute` on the `caption` divs are killing you - make it work with `position: relative` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Is this really the only way to make it work? Position absolute seems to be a good way of allowing a bigger space for the image caption

Comment: Applying `position: absolute` to both the `caption` and the `img` will have the same effect, and doesn't look like it messes up the positioning of your images.

Comment: I've applied `position: absolute` to `img` as well, but it doesn't seem to be working. I think it's down to the `item` having a `position: relative`, but if I change this then the layout completely breaks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4arnZ/ - changed `position: relative` to `position: absolute` on `.item img` and removed the `z-index: 0` from `.item`